# Embedding multiple python 3 interpreters with different built-in modules

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, embedding

I embedded the python 3.6 interpreter successfully in a C++ program, but I have a problem.

I'd like to embed two interpreters in the same program:

- One which can use my C++ defined module (`MyModule`)
- One which can **not** use this module.

Regarding the documentation I should call `PyImport_AppendInittab` before `Py_Initialize` function, so the module will be available in the whole program, but I'd like to create separate interpreters with separate built-in modules.

Calling `Py_Initialize` and `Py_Finalize` doesn't help, the module will be available in the second interpreter, too. By the way calling init and finalize function multiple times causes huge memory leaks, so I think this wouldn't be a good solution even if it would work.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>

#pragma push_macro("_DEBUG")
#undef _DEBUG
#include "Python.h"
#pragma pop_macro("_DEBUG")

static PyObject* Addition (PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    double a = 0.0;
    double b = 0.0;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple (args, "dd", &a, &b)) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    double result = a + b;
    return PyFloat_FromDouble (result);
}

static PyMethodDef ModuleMethods[] =
{
    {"Add", Addition, METH_VARARGS, "Adds numbers."},
    {nullptr, nullptr, 0, nullptr}
};

static PyModuleDef ModuleDef = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "MyModule",
    NULL,
    -1,
    ModuleMethods,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
};

static PyObject* ModuleInitializer (void)
{
    return PyModule_Create (&ModuleDef);
}

int main ()
{
    Py_SetPythonHome (L".");
    Py_SetPath (L"python36.zip\\Lib");

    { // first interpreter
        PyImport_AppendInittab ("MyModule", ModuleInitializer);
        Py_Initialize ();
        PyRun_SimpleString (
            "import MyModule\n"
            "print (MyModule.Add (1, 2))"
        );
        Py_Finalize ();
    }

    { // second interpreter without AppendInittab (should not find MyModule, but it does)
        Py_Initialize ();
        PyRun_SimpleString (
            "import MyModule\n"
            "print (MyModule.Add (1, 2))"
        );
        Py_Finalize ();
    }

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [`Py_NewInterpreter`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_NewInterpreter)?

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but doesn't work, because `PyImport_AppendInittab` should be called before `Py_Initialize`, and `Py_Initialize` creates the module, so all sub-interpreters will see it. The problem is that you can't define modules for sub-interpreters.

Comment: By the way if you embed python 2.7 it works, because the `Py_InitModule` call works for sub-interpreters. But `Py_InitModule` doesn't exist in python 3.6.